# sequelizer generated postgres tables cannot be accessed

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm having problems creating models with sequelizer. Or more accurately I can create models and migrate them, but I cannot access, modify or delete them via psql.

I'm creating the model like this:

```
sequelize model:generate --name Device --attributes pid:string
```

output:

> ```
> Sequelize CLI [Node: 4.6.1, CLI: 3.0.0, ORM: 4.22.6]
>
> WARNING: This version of Sequelize CLI is not fully compatible with
> Sequelize v4. https://github.com/sequelize/cli#sequelize-support
>
> New model was created at
> /home/matti/workspace/db_demo/server/models/device.js . New migration
> was created at
> /home/matti/workspace/db_demo/server/migrations/20171114134820-Device.js
> .
> ```

migrating like this:

> ```
> $ sequelize db:migrate
>
> Sequelize CLI [Node: 4.6.1, CLI: 3.0.0, ORM: 4.22.6]
>
> WARNING: This version of Sequelize CLI is not fully compatible with
> Sequelize v4. https://github.com/sequelize/cli#sequelize-support
>
> Loaded configuration file "server/config/config.json". Using
> environment "development". sequelize deprecated String based operators
> are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better
> security, read more at
> http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators
> node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:236:13
> == 20171114134820-create-device: migrating =======
> == 20171114134820-create-device: migrated (0.044s)
> ```

after this I can see the tables in psql:

```
 device-dev=# \d
           List of relations  
 Schema |      Name      |   Type   | Owner 
--------+----------------+----------+-------  
 public | Devices        | table    | matti  
 public | Devices_id_seq | sequence | matti  
 public | SequelizeMeta  | table    | matti
```

However I cannot list the table:

```
device-dev=# \d Devices 
Did not find any relation named "Devices".
```

my user credentials (using it as matti):

```
                                    List of roles  
   Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
  -----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------  
   matti     | Superuser, Create DB                                       | {}  
   postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

used versions:
Sequelize:
Sequelize CLI [Node: 4.6.1, CLI: 3.0.0, ORM: 4.22.6]

postgres:
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.1

nodejs:
v4.6.1

npm:
2.15.9

I'm working in Ubuntu 16.04.

I've reverted the migration and dropped the db just to be certain. But it didn't have any effect. Nor did restarting the postgres.

I can create, list and delete the db:ses as user "matti" from psql. But not the ones generated by the sequelizer.

Comment: The tables where created using double quotes which makes the names case sensitive. `"Devices"` is a different name then `Devices`. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS  You should tell Sequelize to **not** use double quotes when creating the tables.

Comment: Thanks for super quick reply!

In migrations file there's only single quote:
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Devices', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },...

Comment: Ok, we did the table by hand (same structures that the migrate tried to do) and now it works. I think there's something wrong with the sequelizer + cli combo. 

a_horse_with_no_name: I think your comment should be converted as ansver.